# How is the Knaster–Kuratowski fan connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If the Knaster–Kuratowski fan is totally disconnected with its dispersion point removed, then how is it connected with its dispersion point in place?

How can the connectedness of the points along the lines between the Cantor set and the dispersion point rely on the dispersion point itself?

It seems to me that if the Knaster–Kuratowski fan is connected, then after the  removal of the dispersion point, you'd be left with an infinite set of lines that are themselves internally connected, one for each point in the cantor set.

Comment: There's an article about Knaster–Kuratowski fan (aka Cantor's leaky tent): https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/a-few-of-my-favorite-spaces-cantor-s-leaky-tent/

Comment: @AlexVong I've actually already read that article and it's what introduced me to the Knaster–Kuratowski fan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, ultimately the issue is that you aren't using the definition of connectedness.  You're using your own vague intuition about how it's supposed to behave, but that's not how connectedness is actually defined.  If you want to understand why a space is connected or not, you have to actually use the definition.

The proof that the Knaster-Kuratowski fan is connected is fairly complicated, but here's a much simpler example that shows your intuition can't be right.  Let $K$ be the Knaster-Kuratowski fan with its dispersion point removed, and consider the space $X=K\cup\{\infty\}$ with the topology that a set $U\subseteq X$ is open iff either $U=X$ or $U$ is an open subset of $K$.  Then $X$ is connected, since the only open set containing $\infty$ is all of $X$.  But if you remove $\infty$ from $X$, you're left with $K$ with its usual topology, which is totally disconnected.

As for why $K$ is totally disconnected, keep in mind that the definition of totally disconnected is *not* "any two points can be separated by clopen sets".  Rather, it is "no subset with more than one point is connected".  So even though you can't separate two points along the same line of $K$ by clopen subsets of $K$, they are still "disconnected" from each other in $K$ since there is no connected subset of $K$ that contains both of them.

Comment: I am thinking if the underlying problem is that connectedness is a global property, so even removing one point can change the global structure completely. While our intuition seems to focus on connectedness locally. This leads to me to one question: Is the Knaster-Kuratowski fan locally-connected exactly at its dispersion point?

Comment: You're right that I'm using my intuition, but I'm asking the question because I'm trying to develop a better intuition about it, and also because I've tried re-reading the formal definitions for connected and totally disconnected and I'm unable to reconcile how the fan skirts the line. I understand how the fan without the dispersion point is disconnected, what I don't understand is how it becomes totally disconnected.

Comment: I can see how after the dispersion point is removed that the set can be divided into two disjoint open sets by dividing the plane by an infinite number of different lines that pass through (1/2,1/2). But I don't understand why that should make the lines of the fan to be totally disconnected rather than just split into a bunch of connected lines. And your example with $\infty$ included doesn't really explain that.

Comment: What open sets let us separate every point on every line from every other point on every line that don't work when the dispersion point is included?

Comment: @Shufflepants: Again there is a definition issue (this time with the definition of "totally disconnected"): I've added something on that to the answer.