# showing a path cannot exist

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity, connectedness

> Let $R = S\cup T$ where $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=0, y \in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $T = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x > 0, y \in [0,1]\backslash \mathbb{Q}$. Suppose there was a path from a point $h\in T$ to a point $g\in S$, say $h=(z,p)$ and $g=(0,q)$, where $z>0$, $p$ is irrational, $q$ is rational, and both $p,q\in[0,1]$. We may assume without loss of generality that $\psi:[0,1]\to R$ is a path with $\psi(0)=h$ and $\psi(1)=g$. Prove that $\psi$ cannot exist.

Let $L_p:=\{(x,p):x>0\}$ and define $K=\{t\ge0:\psi([0,t])\subseteq L_p\}$ and $s=\sup K.$ I think that $K$ is both open and closed, but I'm not sure how to prove this. If I can prove this though, the contradiction is easy as then $\psi(1) \in L_p$ but $\psi(1)=g\not\in L_p.$
I tried proving that any sequence $(a_n)$ in $K$ that converges to $b$ in $[0,1]$ converges in $K$, but I was unsuccessful. I need to use the continuity of $\psi$ and the fact that $a_n\to b.$ I tried to do the following. Suppose for a contradiction that $b\not\in K.$ Then we may choose $a=(a_1,a_2)\in \alpha([0,b])\backslash C_r.$ Since $a_n\to b,\forall \epsilon > 0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_n-b| < \epsilon.$ Since $(a_1,a_2)\not\in C_r,$ either $a_1 = 0$ or $a_2\neq r.$ Since $\psi$ is continuous, for all $\epsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0$ so that for all $x\in [0,1], |x-b|<\delta \Rightarrow |\alpha(x)-\alpha(b)| <\epsilon.$ But here I'm stuck.

Also, I'm not sure how to show it's open; I tried proving the complement was closed, but was still unsuccessful.

Comment: I supouse that in the set $S$ there is a mistake and it would be  $y\in [0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$

Comment: The only subsets of $[0,1]$ that are both open and closed in $[0,1]$ are the empty set and $[0,1]$ itself.

Comment: For any function $f$, if $f([0,t_1])$ is a subset of some set $A$, and $t_2<t_1$, that implies that $f([0,t_2]) \subset A$. So it seems to me that $K$ must be either of the form $[0,t]$ or $[0,t)$ for some $t\ge0$.

Comment: @GoRza, it stipulates that $p\notin \mathbb{Q}$, and I don't think your path is in $R$.

Comment: No, unless something is incorrect in my earlier comment, I don't see how it can be open and closed.

Comment: $1\notin K$ since $\psi(1)=g\notin L_p$

Comment: @Joe do you know of some other way to show that such a path $\psi$ does not exist that doesn't involve proving $\psi$ is open and closed?

Comment: No, not off the top of my head. The question changed a lot from the first post. Is this something you are developing, or is it from somewhere?

Comment: If you know $h(z) = (z, p)$, is there a reason not to take the limit as $z \to 0^+$ and deduce $h$ is discontinuous at $0$ because $p \neq q$?

Comment: your question is closely related to the following one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4184825 and in particular to the answer that I give there https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4186540 Note that (a) I added more details to my answer (which may clarify your question here), and (b) I provided an alternative answer there that $F$ (or, in your notation, $R$) is connected, and this alternative answer may be easier to follow https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4196970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is nice, but you should modify your approach. I think the most elegant approach is to use the IVT.

1. $S$ is closed in $R$, thus $\psi^{-1}(S)$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$. It therefore has a minimum $m$. Clearly $m > 0$ because $\psi(0) \notin S$. By construction $\psi([0,m)) \subset T$, $\psi(m) \in S$.
2. Let $\pi : R \to [0,1]$ denote the projection onto the second coordinate and $f = \pi \psi : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. We have $f(0) = p \ne f(m)$. Pick a rational $r$ strictly between $p$ and $f(m)$. The IVT says that there exists $t \in (0,m)$ such that $f(t) = r$. But then $\psi(t)$ lies in $T$ and has  second coordinate $r \in \mathbb Q$ which is a contradiction.